# subquery has too may columns

Tags: postgresql

I would like to get the following return from the example table below.

Example table name "project"

```
project | date | price
abc | 2020-01-07 | 50
abc | 2020-02-14 | 14
abc | 2020-03-20 | 84
ddd | 2020-01-08 | 30
ddd | 2020-02-10 | 45
ddd | 2020-04-10 | 50
```

expected return

```
project|year|quarter|**date**|price
abc | 2020|1|2020-03-20|84
ddd | 2020|1|2020-02-10|45
ddd | 2020|2|2020-04-10|50
```

query

```
select 
 project, 
 date_part('year', project.date),
 date_part('quarter',project.date),
 date
 max(price)     
from project 
where date in ( select
 date_part('year', project.date),
 date_part('quarter',project.date)
 from project
)
group by 1,2,3
```

If I use the query above, it returns "subquery has too many columns" and an error direct to where clause.

How can I fix this problem?
Thank you in advance.

#### Update

The following code works for me.
If you guys have another idea, I would like to take and have a look.
Thank you.

```
SELECT  
    b.project ,
    b.year AS 'year', 
    b.quarter AS 'quarter',
    max(b.date ) AS 'date',   
    max(b.price ) AS 'price'  
FROM (SELECT a.project, 
             date_part('year', a.date) AS year,
             date_part('quarter', a.date) AS quarter,
             a.date,
             a.price   
      FROM  project a) b 
group by b.project, b.year , b.quarter
```

Comment: I don't see any reason for your outer query at all. Remove it and run what is now the subquery by itself. And the reason that you're getting the error is that the syntax you're using does not exist. Find a good SQL tutorial or book.

Comment: The `group by` seems useless as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The group by is necessary when you use a column aggregation. In this case, I'm trying to get "max(size)". ..  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  bb.project ,    bb.year 'year', bb.quorter 'quorter',   max(bb.date ) 'date',   max(bb.price ) 'price'  
FROM (SELECT    aa.project ,  year([date]) 'year',DATEPART(QUARTER,[date]) 'quorter',
      [date]   'date' ,   aa.price   'price'    FROM  project  aa) bb 
group by bb.project,bb.year ,   bb.quorter
```

i use sql server

Comment: @Kaycee: that query is invalid for Postgres (and invalid standard SQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : It could be.  But the query works for me. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @Kaycee: then you are not using Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: okay. Thanks. I will have a look at a different way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the subquery altogether:

```
select
  project,
  date_part('year', project.date) as year,
  date_part('quarter', project.date) as quarter,
max(price)
from project
group by 1, 2, 3
```

---

Consider renaming the `project` column of the `project` table to `name` or `code` to increase clarity and decrease confusion.

Comment: Hi, Bohemian thank you for that. However, there is a problem. If I use your query, then I cant get the date of the max price of a quarter of a year.

Comment: Thank you for your advice on the project column name. It's is a good point.